# Django manage.py shell

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Python and Django. And what I don't understand:

Why if I use this code (from django tutorial):

```
from django.db import models

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    # other functions...


class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

from `manage.py shell` all works well. And when I try to build this code in SublimeText2 I get the following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DATABASES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Why in the second case Django does not know which `settings` file to use?

Comment: You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.    ... the shell does that automatically

Comment: Is your manage.py setting the env variable ? The automatically generated manage.py does this: os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project_name.settings")